# When using a JQuery Plugin that opens a modal window, can I format the description with HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, inject

I am designing a website for a manufacturing company and I am using a modal window as a "pop-up" that the user can then fill out order information into and submit to the sales reps. Is it possible that in the "description" that is displayed in the modal window that I inject some HTML/PHP so that it will be formatted?

JQuery:

```
$('#ContactUs').ModalWindow({
            height: '750',
            width: '750',
            title: 'Does This Work?',
            description: *I Want To Input An Order Form here*
                                    });
```

Comment: link to your modal window plugin?

Comment: You can't inject PHP because when it reaches that point, it's all client side, and PHP needs to run server side, however you can inject HTML.

Comment: This is a link to the modal window I'm using: http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-box-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the plugin for your modal window. Generally, you have 2 choices when loading content into a modal window:

- predefined content
- content loaded dynamically via ajax or similar

If you predefine the content, you could use PHP to generate the content if the javascript is in your PHP page. If you want to use ajax, this might be better because then you could hit a PHP page which would give you whatever dynamic content you like.